# Computer freezing while watching Flash videos from net

Tags: freeze, filesystem-corruption

I have a Windows 7 home basic, while watching videos from net (within 5 minutes) computer starts to freeze and shows 100 percent CPU usage. I first thought it's a browser issue but watching videos from different browsers also has the same issue. My system runs the latest Firefox browser and all my plugins (including Flash) is up-to-date.

After this when I shutdown/restart the computer it will go to the login window with out any problem. From there when I tried to log in to any account, the system starts to freeze and again I have to start and run Windows in safe mode (which doesn't show any problem).

I read it in an article to do these steps

```
CMD->sfc/scannow

chkdsk
```

after that only my system works normally, even now I can't watch any videos on the net otherwise it starts freezing( I can watch downloaded videos in computer without a problem) and have to do the whole process once more (which takes a lot of time).

while running **sfc/scannow** its showed results that `some of the files are corrupted and it could not be repaired.`  Can this be the cause for freezing of my computer while running Flash videos? or is it a hardware related problem? What different steps do I have to take to correct those corrupt files?

- System restore works only some times.

Comment: Very likely to be hardware related. What spec is the machine - Processor type, processor speed, how much RAM, which graphics chip, how much video RAM?

Comment: @Shevek Intel Core i3-370M Processor (2.4GHz, 3MB Cache),Intel HD Graphics,3 GB DDR3-1066MHz RAM,320 HDD ..how can i check whether if its hardware ?

Comment: Well, I was thinking more about lack of hardware as I had problems playing flash videos on a low spec netbook. Increasing the RAM to 1GB solved that. Your machine spec shouldn't be a problem at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some problem in your hard disk due to sectors. You flash player plugin or browser may stored on some bad sectors even after reinstallation also. So only you faced these problems.

How ever your should full format your Operating system installed drive for best performance and to avoid future problems also.