# Freezing of computer while watching flash videos (contd)

Tags: freeze, hardware-failure, flash-player, laptop-repair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer freezing while watching Flash videos from net](https://superuser.com/questions/484844/computer-freezing-while-watching-flash-videos-from-net)

I have asked this similar question [Computer freezing while watching Flash videos from net](https://superuser.com/questions/484844/computer-freezing-while-watching-flash-videos-from-net) two week before. As i mentioned in my previous problem my computer freezes while watching online videos showing 100% cpu usage. I have tried the suggestions given in that query and I have formated my whole computer and installed windows and other softwares (with latest updates) but the problem still presisting. If i watch a video online approximately after one hour my system shows very high cpu usage and when i close my browser cpu usage comes to normal(i tried to watch [Cybergeddon](http://screen.yahoo.com/cybergeddon/) but  my computer is freezing from start,and also other youtube videos).

Can you tell me whether its an hardware problem? if yes can you give any possible explanation( eg:motherboard problem,over heating etc) because i want to tell those reasons to my computer mechanic.

Comment: If you still have the same issue please don't post another question about it. You can always edit your older question with additional details or even place a bounty on it to draw attention

Comment: Are your video drivers up to date? Have you tried a browser other than Firefox to see if it behaves the exact same way? Try [disabling GPU rendering/hardware acceleration](http://blog.acsystem.sk/windows-7/how-disable-gpu-acceleration-in-ie9) if it is being used and see if that helps. You can also try [turning off Desktop Composition](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/127411-desktop-composition-enable-disable.html) and see.

Comment: @Karan yes drivers are uptodate and i also tried in ie but having same result.